# How to access map values with dot notation

Tags: java

if you have a class with a set of methods and your are using netbean to code 
when accessing the methods i just type the intiated class with a dot and all viewable methods are displayed for you to choose of your choice

I would like to do the same to in maps . Instead of using getObject(key) to just type the map 
with a dot and all keys are displayed for me to choose any key of my choice . In this case I don't have to know the keys in the map. please help

Comment: Unfortunately it is impossible.

Comment: The keys in the map will only be known at execution time. How would you expect the IDE to suggest them?

Comment: Hint: if you're planning to use a Map with keys that are known at compile time, chances are you just want to write a class to hold those properties. Then the IDE can even autocomplete what you write!

Comment: @JoachimSauer Not to mention lookups will *always* be in `O(1)` thanks to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible without reflection. Maps are simply objects that are instances of a class implementing `Map`. It is not possible for dot-notation to happen. Since they are dynamic, the compiler and/or IDE *cannot* resolve any lookups in the map ahead of time.

Of course, with reflection, it could hypothetically do this at runtime, but it would be wasteful, inefficient, and be even more horrendous code. Your IDE would also not be around and ready to fill in then.

Answer (score 0):

Keys are added in the runtime, and the runtime object values depend on various inputs (including user input) so that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

map is populated at runtime, you cannot retrieve the runtime information at compile time :)